# How to mount a disk at startup in Ubuntu? Disks tool isn't working

Tags: ubuntu, mount, disk

I go into the Disks tool, and select the drive and select "mount at startup" and "show user interface", but it doesn't do it at reboot, ever. My Steam game library is on there so its difficult to go and mount it every time I want to play a game.

Comment: Add it to /etc/fstab

Comment: clear instruction which was very helpful for me: How to automount hard disks on boot in Ubuntu: https://www.fosslinux.com/4216/how-to-automount-hard-disk-partitions-in-ubuntu.htm/

Answer (score 1):

You can use file `/etc/fstab` to mount drives at startup.

1. The first is view the drive to mount with `fdisk -l`
2. The second step is go to `/etc/fstab` and write a line like this:

   /dev/sda1 /mnt    ntfs-3g users,uid=33,gid=1000,umask=0000,nofail     0       3

The first column is the drive listed with `fdisk -l`, the second column is the path where drive is going to be mounted, the third is the filesystem format, the fourth column are options to mount like the user(uid) and group (gid), the fifth column is to dump filesystem, and last column is the order to check with fschk

Answer (score 0):

Please be aware for you as a fyi not all your steam games will work with linux or maybe not at all due to using DirectX instead of OpenGL witch linux users. You may need to re-download them

But you like take a chance:

1. Open Terminal, edit with nano or your favorite Text editor
   Using the following file to edit: `/etc/stab`
   eg `sudo nano /etc/fstab`

In what I am using, fedora fstab would look like this... results may differ per disro, system.

```
#
# /etc/fstab
# Created by anaconda on Sat Oct  5 00:53:52 2019
#
# Accessible filesystems, by reference, are maintained under '/dev/disk/'.
# See man pages fstab(5), findfs(8), mount(8) and/or blkid(8) for more info.
#
# After editing this file, run 'systemctl daemon-reload' to update systemd
# units generated from this file.
#
UUID=f8411693-151f-4a8c-91b7-1c842ba8fd09 /                       xfs     defaults        0 0      0 2
UUID=0399513c-ccf9-4f20-ba02-3c68533a8fe6 none                    swap    defaults        0 0
```

We will need a /dev/sdx for the NTFS device for windows:

for that: `lsblk` to look up your /dev/sdx

2. Insert a new line that would do the "auto-mounting"

```
/dev/sdx       /mnt/c-drive     ntfs-3g defaults,nls=utf8,umask=000,dmask=027,fmask=137,uid=1000,gid=1000,windows_names 0 0
```

make a folder `sudo mkdir /mnt/c-drive` for the mount point!

Before Reboot:

to do a test to see if it all works: `mount -a` as root

if no errrors passed while remounting all drives

your good to reboot!

I kinda stole this from: https://askubuntu.com/questions/113733/how-do-i-correctly-mount-a-ntfs-partition-in-etc-fstab

Comment: if you have any questions anyone feel free to ask! I really enjoy helping other people!